# Symfony 2 Login on main domain only

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, subdomain

I am working on a application using multiple subdomains :

- .domain.com
- admin.domain.com
- {username}.domain.com

  and so on.

I am using the FOSUserBundle to handle my users and I am wondering how I could force users to login only on the main .domain.com.

For example, when a user is trying to access the administration, redirect him to http://domain.com/login instead of http://admin.domain.com/login.

I was thinking about a LoginListener somewhere, but I have no idea where I could create it and how to override the login process.

Any ideas ??
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a host directive to your login route.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
login_route:
    path:     /login
    host:     "domain.com"
```

Then use this route in your firewall configuration as the `login_path`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        your_firewall_name:
            # ...
            form_login:
                 login_path: login_route
                 # ...
```

Now everytime the url for `login_route` is generated it automatically refers to the host `domain.com`.

Comment: I tried with the host but I forgot the login_path ! I'll try that as soon as I can, thanks ! :)

Comment: Thank your for your help it works perfectly, except for the logout but it is just a link most of the time so it's ok :)