# Symfony2 with Fosuserbundle firewall redirect from subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have one Symfony2 app with 3 subdomains:

- domain.com
- app.domain.com
- api.domain.com

the %domain% parameters is : domain.com

I have setup routing like this :

```
domain_app:
    resource: "@DomainAppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    host: "app.%domain%"

domain_api:
    resource: "@DomainApiBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    host: "api.%domain%"

domain_front:
    resource: "@DomainFrontBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    host: "%domain%"

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    host:"%domain%"
```

And security like this :

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        host: "%domain%"
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: front
        logout:true
        anonymous:true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, host: "app.%domain%" }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, host: "api.%domain%" }
```

My subdomain app and api are secured like i want with http://domain.com/login working perfectly.

But if i'm not logged when i load directly http://app.domain.com, i'm redirected to 
http://app.domain.com/login.
I don't want to be redirect on the subdomain, i want the firewall redirect if not logged only  on main http://domain.com/login

Can anyone help me for that ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to override the login route and use that in your main security configuration. Don't forget to add host partemerter to the new login path. I think this answer can help you:

[Symfony 2 Login on main domain only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257027/symfony-2-login-on-main-domain-only)